# Динамический массив СИ

Tags: c, строки, указатели, память

Есть динамический массив

```
char** order;
char temp[50]
int size = 9;
int osize = 5;
order = (char**)malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
order[i] = (char*)malloc(osize * sizeof(char));
free(order);
```

Дальше я заполняю его через `scanf_s("%s", temp, 49); order[1] = temp;`и тд, но в итоге все елементы будут равны последнему значению. На `free(order);`выдаёт ошибку. Сама студия жалуется на разыменование пустого указателя order в этой строке `order[i] = (char*)malloc(osize * sizeof(char));` Где ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Очень интересное решение. Итак, у вас есть указатель на выделенную память (которую потом можно будет удалить через `free`) `order[1]`.

Вы *перезаписываете* этот *указатель*

```
 order[1] = temp;
```

и теперь он (как и все остальные, по окончании работы) указывает на память, выделенную в стеке массиву `temp`. Еще раз и медленно - все указатели указывают на одну и ту же память в стеке (к которой применять `free` нельзя). Т.е. все указывают на одну и ту же последнюю строку.

Видимо, вы просто прогуляли лекцию, где рассказывалось, что для копирования строк используются функции наподобие [`strcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy)...

Еще - вам точно хватит места под вводимые слова? Все же в `temp` может поместиться 49-символьная строка, а в `order[i]` - только четырехсимвольная...

И еще - судя по вашим `(char*)` перед `malloc` вы все же компилируете в режиме C++, а не С - в С это приведение не требуется.

P.S. VC++ ни о каком разыменовании в указанном вами месте не говорит. Только о том, что после `temp[50]` вы точку с запятой забыли.

Comment: Хорошо, я `order[1]` и остальные вписал сразу в `scanf_s`, теперь все строки на месте. По поводу `free`, как тогда её правильно применить? По заданию в конце программы нужно освобождать память. Про `temp[50]`, это тут забыл написать `;`, в коде всё есть. Но всё ещё жалуется на разыменование пустого указателя [скриншот](https://ibb.co/dGGB7Cc). А после выполнения всего кода, выдаёт ошибку "нарушение прав доступа при исполнении по адресу 0xCCCCCCCC", хоть и весь код выполнился. Что здесь может быть не так?

Comment: Я не вижу "как" - как же я могу ответить, "что не так"?...

Comment: [скриншот1](https://ibb.co/2YKyFS9) [скриншот2](https://ibb.co/wyM6WsH)

Comment: Ну вы же, видно, не прочли мой ответ, и продолжаете заниматься присваиванием типа `order[1] = "Prepare";`...